# How to bind listview to custom item collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

How do I get my custom item collection to show up in my list view using WPF data bindings?
I have a tried to make a ViewModel and a custom collection that the ViewModel manipulates, in an attempt to get this collection to show up in a listview. I have a view model and a custom collection and a custom item class:

```
public class TranslationViewModel
{
    public TranslationViewModel() { this.translatedItems = new TransListboxCollection(); }
    public TransListboxCollection translatedItems { get; private set; }

    public void addTranslatedItem(TransListboxItem message)
    {
        translatedItems.Add(message);
    }
}

public class TransListboxCollection : BindingList<TransListboxItem>
{

    public TransListboxCollection()
    {
        //initialize
    }
}

public class TransListboxItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _rawString;
    private String _tString;

    public String rawString 
    {
        get { return _rawString; }
        set { _rawString = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("rawString"); } 
    }

    public String tString 
    {
        get { return _tString; }
        set { _tString = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("tString"); } 
    }


    public TransListboxItem(String value)
    {
        this.tString = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.tString;
    }
}
```

I have a WPF element hosted in a windows form

```
    public partial class wGlobal : UserControl
{
    public TranslationViewModel tvm { get; set; }

    public wGlobal()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = tvm;
    }

}
```

The XAML code for such

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MHF_Transcoder_3" x:Class="MHF_Transcoder_3.wGlobal" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="1000" d:DesignHeight="150">
<Grid Width="1000" Height="150">
    <ListView x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding tvm}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1000" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding tString}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding rawString}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

and I have that element hosted in a windows form control

```
 public partial class frmGlobal : Form
{
    wGlobal xamlForm;
    TranslationViewModel tvm;

    public frmGlobal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tvm = new TranslationViewModel();
        xamlForm = (wGlobal)elementHost1.Child;
        xamlForm.tvm = tvm;
    }

    delegate void addMessageCallback(TransListboxItem message);
    public void addMessage(TransListboxItem message) {
            tvm.addTranslatedItem(message);
    }

}
```

When I get the program up and launch everything, all my list view says is "System.Windows.DataTemplate". I've never really worked with WPF or data bindings before. I'm open to any and all advice and suggestions. Please help me get this setup and properly working.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap Datatemplate with ItemTemplate

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding translatedItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1000" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding tString}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding rawString}" />
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Also as the tvm is the datacontext, you must bind to the collection "translatedItems"

Comment: I was able to get it to display something with <ListView.ItemTemplate> but now the listview itself is still empty

Comment: See that now It's bound to translatedItems @BustyLoli-Chan

Comment: But adding a translated item to the collection doesn't cause a change in the listview

Comment: Why don't you use an ObservableCollection?

Comment: Alright, I bound the listview to translatedItems, and added the item template, but the listview is still empty. I used BindingList<> because I read somewhere that it had advantages over ObservableCollection. I can switch it and see if it works. It did not work.

Comment: I made a small test here, I manually added an item to the translateditems before assigning the datacontext and I can see it in the listview.

Comment: Can I have a link to this code sample? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I didn't use Winforms host, just a simple WPF project

Comment: I'm still just curious. Anything to look at would be a good reference at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77252/discussion-between-jat-and-bustyloli-chan).